# sfdx scanner:run dont understand User Mode

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-development, sfdx

I try to use the new User Mode DML Operation as describe here =>

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_enforce_usermode.htm

The code can be deploy successfully.

```
Upsert As User Events;
```

However when i run the scanner it's showing error.

```
sfdx scanner:run -e pmd -t force-app --category '!Documentation,!Best Practices,!Design,!Code Style' -o security-scan.html
```

I am getting this error on my security scanner result. How to update the scanner so that it's can understand the User Mode?

```
Caused by: net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.ast.ParseException: apex.jorje.services.exception.ParseException: Syntax(error = UnexpectedToken(loc = (182, 16, 1699, 1701), token = 'as'))
```

Comment: No i didnt find.